# VBScript Function

Tags: function, vbscript

I am a novice and have written a VBS Function but it keeps giving me an error. I have searched the MS site and the syntax looks correct. What is wrong? Here's what i've tried :

```
Function IsTheNumberTooLow()
IsTheNumberTooLow = intUserNumber < intRandomNo
MsgBox = "Your guess was too low. Try again", cGreetingMsg
End Function
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Just says syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your syntax is incorrect. Also I am guessing your values are global, its best to pass in the values or set them inside the function. Try something like this:

```
Function IsTheNumberTooLow(intUserNumber, intRandomNo)
   Dim cGreetingMsg

   IsTheNumberTooLow = False
   cGreetingMsg = "Hello All"

   If intUserNumber < intRandomNo Then
      MsgBox "Your guess was too low. Try again", vbOKOnly, cGreetingMsg
      IsTheNumberTooLow = True
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: The goal is to replace the If-Then-Statement with a Function. I tried what you suggested and still get an error message. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi, have just tested the code [here](http://www.landofcode.com/online-code-editor.php?file=vbsHead) and worked ok.

Comment: The "If Then" statement you posted will run and state the message, so it can be used without the Function statement. So I need the Function to replace the "If Then" statement, if that makes sense.

Comment: Check your msgbox code and ensure it contains the 'vbOKOnly' parameter. This can be replaced by 0. ie.. MsgBox "Your guess was too low. Try again", 0, cGreetingMsg

Answer (score 0):

Do you assign a value to `cGreetingMsg` elsewhere? And `intUserNumber` or `intRandomNo`?

Comment: Yes. After Dim in the beginning of the script.

Comment: The error message shows the line and col at the beginning of the word Function.

Comment: `MsgBox  "Your guess was too low. Try again", cGreetingMsg`